# php function with [loop] and [if] isn't working

Tags: php

So I tried making function with nested loop and if in it but somehow when I try to open the file it doesn't show anything.. here's my codes

```
<?php

      $result[0] = "no";
      $condition[0] = "yes";

      function cek() {

       for ($i=0; $i<2; $i++) {

        if ($result[$i] == "no") {

            for ($i=0; $i<2; $i++) {

                if ($condition[$i] == "yes") {
                    echo ("means yes");
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    echo ("means no");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}


cek();   


?>
```

any help will be appreciated. thank you

Comment: Your inner loop uses the same variable as your outer loop. Change one, but don't use the same for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the result of the execution of your code :

```
$ php test.php
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: result in /home/.../test.php on line [...]
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: result in /home/.../test.php on line [...]
```

The line concern is :

```
if ($result[$i] == "no")
```

Variables `$result` and `$condition` are undefined in your function, you must either pass as an argument to your function or use global (which should be avoided for this case).

Moreover, this loop will also fail :

```
for ($i=0; $i<2; $i++)
```

Indeed, "2" isn't the size of `$condition` (or `$result`). You could use `sizeof($condition)` or `count($condition)` instead.

And finally, you shouldn't use the same increment (`$i`) in your both nested loops.

This code will work :

```
<?php
$result = array("no");
$condition = array("yes");

function cek(array $result, array $condition) {
    for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($result); $i++) {
        if ($result[$i] == "no") {
            for ($j=0; $j<sizeof($condition); $j++) {
                echo "means " . (($condition[$i] == "yes") ? "yes" : "no");
                break;
            }
       }
    }
}

cek($result, $condition);
```

But I'm not sure that's exactly what you're looking to do ;)

Comment: "Variables $result and $condition are undefined in your function, you must either pass as an argument to your function or use global (which should be avoided for this case)." can you give an example, because I'm kinda new to php so I don't really know about this. thank you

Comment: @user3266318 : I've added an example ;)